# За_тем или затем?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Есть ли ошибка в слитном написании **затем** ниже:

> явившегося то ли за подаянием, то ли **затем**, чтобы вынудить себе чего-то неположенного.

У меня есть сильное чувство, что здесь нужно писать *за тем* (за чем?).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: ...**явившегося то ли за подаянием, то ли затем, чтобы вынудить себе чего-то неположенного.**

Сравнить: явившегося то ли за подаянием, то ли  чтобы вынудить себе чего-то неположенного.

**Пояснение**

Союз со значением цели **имеет следующие варианты:** чтобы, для того чтобы, с тем чтобы, затем чтобы.

**Пример:**

Большинство подходили именно **затем, чтобы взглянуть** на него хотя бы издали. [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)]

Comment: Блестящий ответ!